# no complete word after decoding

Tags: c, decode, bit, parity

as an expirement i am trying to work with file handeling and adidas. but for some reason my decode doesn't work completely.

what the problem is: when i use the word ferret as input, encode this, channel and decode it outputs the word ferret. as soon as I put another word in it, it doesn't come out completely after the decode. for instance guitar, after i do the same steps guatar will exit. does someone maybe know how i can make it work?

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *inputFile, *outputFile;

    uint8_t charFile;
    uint8_t highNibble;

    int i = 1;

    uint8_t byte;
    uint8_t d0, d1, d2, d3;
    uint8_t p0, p1, p2;

    uint8_t finalByteParity = 0;


    int nibble; //for getting the high nibble


    if (argc == 3)
    {
        printf("The first argument is %s\n", argv[0]);
        printf("The first argument is %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("The first argument is %s\n", argv[2]);
        inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");  //opening the .txt file and reading it
        outputFile = fopen(argv[2], "w"); //opening the .txt file and writing to it

        if (inputFile == NULL)
        {
            printf("There has been a problem while opening the file %s\n", argv[1]); //show this when a error occus while opening the .txt
        }
        else if (outputFile == NULL)
        {
            printf("There has been a problem while writing to the file %s\n", argv[2]); //show this when a error occus while opening the .txt
        }
        else
        {
            charFile = fgetc(inputFile); //Used to obtain the input form a file as a single character at a time.
            while (!feof(inputFile)) //Found this function on the internet since the res != 0 didn't work. This while means the following: "While we haven't tried to read past end of the inputFile" it keeps going till all the bytes are read.
            {
                byte = (int)charFile;
                //get nibble
                nibble = (byte >> 3) & 0x07; //set the first byte on 0

                //d0, d1, d2, d3 + nibble
                d0 = (nibble >> 0) & 0b0001;
                d1 = (nibble >> 1) & 0b0001;
                d2 = (nibble >> 2) & 0b0001;
                d3 = (nibble >> 3) & 0b0001;
                //p0, p1, p2
                p0 = (d0 + d1 + d2) % 2;
                p1 = (d0 + d1 + d3) % 2;
                p2 = (d1 + d2 + d3) % 2;

                // Add p0
                finalByteParity = p0 << 0;
                // Add p1
                finalByteParity |= p1 << 1;
                // Add p2
                finalByteParity |= p2 << 2;

              
                uint8_t checkByteParity = byte & 0x07;
                uint8_t checkFinalParity = finalByteParity & 0x07;

                int fullCheck = checkByteParity ^ checkFinalParity;

                if(fullCheck == 7)
                {
                    nibble ^= 0x02; //the wrong bit gets flipped back to the correct one
                }
                if(fullCheck == 3)
                {
                    nibble ^= 0x01;
                }
                if(fullCheck == 5)
                {
                    nibble ^= 0x04;
                }
                if(fullCheck == 6)
                {
                    nibble ^= 0x08;
                }

                if (i % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    uint8_t restoredByte =  highNibble << 4 | nibble;
                    fputc(restoredByte, outputFile);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    highNibble = nibble;                                    
                }                                                                                                                   
                charFile = fgetc(inputFile);
                i++;

            }
        }
       
        fclose(inputFile);  //close the input file
        fclose(outputFile); //close the output ifle
    }
    else
    {
        printf("you need to give 3 arguments");
    }
}
```

Comment: `charFile` should be declared as an `int`, since **(A)** that's what `fgetc` returns, **(B)** you wouldn't need to cast it to an `int` when copying the value to `byte`, and **(C)** you wouldn't need to use the `feof` function, which should never be used for loop control. If you change the type of `charFile` to `int`, you can write the loop as `while ((charFile = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF)`, and you can remove the calls to `fgetc` before the loop and at the end of the loop.

Comment: You have `printf("The first argument is %s\n", argv[0]); printf("The first argument is %s\n", argv[1]); printf("The first argument is %s\n", argv[2]);` — it would be conventional to use `second` and `third` in the second and third format strings.